# Запуск проекта Gulp

Tags: gulp

Следуя туториалу, я написал вот такой код в gulpfile.js

```
let project_folder="dist";
let source_folder="src";

let path={
    build:{
        html:project_folder+"/",
        css:project_folder+"/css/",
        js:project_folder+"/js/",
        img:project_folder+"/img/",
        fonts:project_folder+"/fonts/",
    },
    scr:{
        html: source_folder+"/*.html",
        css: source_folder+"/scss/style.scss",
        js: source_folder+"/js/script.js",
        img: source_folder+"/img/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|ico|svg|webp)",
        fonts: source_folder+"/fonts/*.ttf",
    },
    watch:{
        html:source_folder+"/**/*.html",
        css:source_folder+"/scss/**/*.scss",
        js:source_folder+"/js/**/*.js",
        img:source_folder+"/img/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|ico|svg|webp)",
    },
    clean: "./" + project_folder+"/",
}

let { src, dest } = require("gulp"),
    gulp = require("gulp"),
    browsersync = require("browser-sync").create();

function browserSync(params) {
    browsersync.init({
        server:{
            baseDir: "./" + project_folder+"/"
        },
        port: 3000,
        notify: false
    })
}

function html() {
    return src(path.src.html)
        .pipe(dest(path.build.html))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

let build = gulp.series(html);
let watch = gulp.parallel(build,browserSync);

exports.html = html;
exports.build = build;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = watch;
```

Но при вводе в терминале "gulp" выдаётся следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что надо исправить в коде, чтобы всё запустилось, как и должно?

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в объекте `path` - поле не `src`, а `scr` у вас названо. Вообще советую разобраться в стандартных ошибках. Если пишет `Cannot read properties of undefined` - значит интерпретатору попался не объект, у которого нужно прочитать поле, а другой тип, в данном случае `undefined`